# spring integration outbound webservice gateway with dynamic uri and trust all certs

Tags: web-services, ssl, spring-integration, dynamic-url

I am building a service that talks to multiple devices using SOAP over https. These devices expose the same webservice API (same wsdl). New devices can be added to this scheme any time at runtime.

I need to dynamically query each of these devices and any that may be added in the future. Each of these devices have a self signed certificate for ssl. The service that I am building needs to be implemented using Spring Integration.

Given the above I have two main questions:

1. In Spring Integration how can I, dynamically at runtime, assign the service uri.
2. How do I trust all the certs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "How do I trust all the certs..." - That could be a bad idea. Ar you talking about Opportunistic Encryption or [Opportunistic Security](http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-kent-opportunistic-security-01.txt)? If so, you might as well use Anonymous Diffie-Hellman (ADH) and avoid certificates all together.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help Gary and Artem.

I was able to solve the problem of dynamic uri with a thread local variable and and SPEL.

For the trust of self signed certs, I implemented and new message-sender using the httpclient. HttpClient provides a TrustSelfSignedStrategy. I used this to trust all self signed certs. The solutions seems to be working. Following is the code if anyone has similar needs in the future.

```
    KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

    InputStream instream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(trustStoreFile);

     try {
        trustStore.load(instream, trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
    } finally {
        instream.close();
    }

    SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
    builder.loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
    SSLContext sslcontext = builder.build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext,SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
    httpClientBuilder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf);
    httpClientBuilder.addInterceptorFirst(new RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor());

    if (credentials!=null){
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,credentials);
        httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
    }

    CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpclient = httpClientBuilder.build();
    setHttpClient(closeableHttpclient);
```

Comment: hey, do you mind sharing a bit more on how/where you use this code?

Answer (score 0):

The first question is easy; see the XSD documentation:

```
The Destination URI for this Web Service Gateway. If the URI should be determined at runtime
(e.g. registry lookup), then configure a 'destination-provider' reference instead. Aternatively,
this URI may include {placeholders} whose values are determined by evaluating SpEL expressions
provided via 'uri-variable' sub-elements. The root object for those evaluations is the actual
request Message at runtime, i.e. you can access its payload or headers in the expression.
```

and the [documentation about URI placeholders](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ws.html#outbound-uri).

I don't know if you can dynamically add keys/certs to the keystore/truststore at runtime; I've never tried.

Comment: Thanks Gary! I need to change the uri while the service is running so that I can hit different devices. My understanding of the paragraph that you posted is that the uri can be "calculated" once but cannot be changed thereafter to point to a different uri while the service is running. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: No; it is evaluated for each message. In the case of the destination provider the API (`getDestination()`) doesn't provide any context so you would have to pass some context to a custom implementation using a `ThreadLocal` or similar. Using uri variables is simpler - the variables are evaluated based on the message when it is sent. Again, see section 31.4 in the link in my answer. `uri=http://{host}/{path}`.

Comment: You can build `uri` manual somewher upstream or just extract it from the `headers` and just have only one `uri variable` - `uri="{uri}"`